# How to check PIPESTATUS equivalent during PROMPT_COMMAND execution?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, prompt

I have a custom `$PROMPT_COMMAND` in bash that logs the last executed command and its return code. I was using `$?` for the latter happily until I realized that for piped commands this was insufficient. I thought I'd log `${PIPESTATUS[@]}` instead.

Unfortunately `$PIPESTATUS` seems to be set **after** the invocation of the `$PROMPT_COMMAND`. Is there any *trickery* that I can use to access this information during the execution of `$PROMPT_COMMAND`?

Comment: This works for me: `PROMPT_COMMAND='true | false | true; echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"'`

Comment: Try this:
`PROMPT_COMMAND='echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"'` and then run `true | false | true`

Comment: Now I understand your problem. But it works fine with my old Ubuntu 11.04. Output is: 0 1 0

Comment: @JacobodeVera Doing exactly this works for me, as it should. Did you test exactly this? If not, what exactly are you doing, and what version of bash are you running?

Comment: I was doing it wrong, see my comment in the answer below. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Commands within your prompt command function alter `PIPESTATUS`, `bash` saves and restores `PIPESTATUS` (and `$?`) after your prompt command, see [the description of the intended behaviour here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!msg/gnu.bash.bug/Fgp8yg4ldy0/csRxFb0_5ZQJ).

The trick is to save `$PIPESTATUS[]` (and/or `$?`) in the *very first statement* of your function, after that the original values are overwritten.

```
function myprompt() {
   _pipestatus=( "${PIPESTATUS[@]}" )
   echo "current: ${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
   echo "cached : ${_pipestatus[@]}"
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=myprompt
```

then:

```
$ true | false | true
current: 0
cached : 0 1 0
```

I do something similar to what you have described, but within a trap handler function for `ERR` rather than a prompt command.

Comment: Ah, of course! I was doing the same thing for the return code and forgot about it completely, then tried to capture PIPESTATUS way below, after doing other things.

Answer (score 0):

Mmh perhaps it depends also on the bash version.

Let's try this simple assignment into your bash profile configuration:

> export PROMPT_COMMAND="echo status=$?"

bash 4.1.2 works fine.
At the bash prompt I digit a non-existent command:

> status=127

bash 3.2.25 always prints

> status=0

At the command-line, I check the variable

> echo $PROMPT_COMMAND

On the working host, it corresponds to my assignment.
On the other host, its value is

> history -a;history -n;echo status=$?

Why are there these commands? Are them the cause of the problem?